# removing initial items from nested lists

Tags: python

I have a script which imports data and I am storing these in nested lists.

I have one list which instructs how many elements from each sub-list are to be discarded.

How do I do this?

I know how to do it manually, but I want to be able to upload a csv file into my program, and then let it run.

I have run the same line of data twice in csv file to try and make it simpler for me to fix, so I have

```
starting_index = [203,203]
```

but in principle this could have a 100 or so elements of different number.

I then have a whole series of nested lists.  The number of elements in my starting_index matches the number of sub-lists within each list so at the moment there are only two sub-lists in each nested list.

I wanted to define a function that I could call on to pare each list. I know what is wrong with my code, but I do not know how to make it work.

```
def index_filter(original_list, new_list):
    for i in starting_index:
            print(i)
            for index, value in enumerate(original_list):
                    for item,element in enumerate(value):
                            if item >= i:
                                    new_list[index].append(element)
```

I realise now that this does not work, and the problems is the

```
for i in starting_index:
```

because when it finishes the first element in starting index, it then goes on to the next and appends more data.  It doesn't error, but it does not do what I wanted it to do.   I just want to remove in this case the first 203 elements from sub-list 1, and the first 203 elements from sub list two, but in principle those numbers will change.

I try and use enumerate all the time, and perhaps it's not appropriate here.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Edit:  Some sample data:

```
starting_index = [2,1,3]
list_one = [[15,34,67,89,44], [44,23,67,88,45,67,233,567,41,56.4],[45,6734,5,67,29,55,6345,23,89,45,6,8,3,4,5,876]]
```

ideal result:
    list_one = [[67,89,44],[23,67,23,67,88,45,67,233,567,41,56.4],[67,29,55,6345,23,89,45,6,8,3,4,5,876]]

I have just come across the del statement which I am looking at, and I'll also have a look at the slice suggestion. Thanks

Edit:  I tried the solution but I can't get it to work.

I tried that but when I put some test data in I get back the original unaltered list.

How do I access the output?

My test script:

```
original_list=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38]]

starting_index=[3,6]

def index_filter(original_list, starting_index):
    return [value[i:] for i, value in zip(starting_index, original_list)]

index_filter(original_list, starting_index)

print(index_filter)

print(original_list)
```

Outputs a strange message and the original unaltered list

```
<function index_filter at 0x039CC468>
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38]]
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you add some example data?

Comment: Use a slice: `new_list.append(value[i:])`

Comment: Why is that a strange message? `print(index_filter)` prints the function object itself, it doesn't call it or print the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the `starting_index` and `original_list` in parallel, so use `zip()`.

And you can use the slice `value[i:]` to get the part of a list starting at an index, rather than looping.

```
def index_filter(original_list, starting_index):
    return [value[i:] for i, value in zip(starting_index, original_list)]

original_list=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38]]

starting_index=[3,6]

new_list = index_filter(original_list, starting_index)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: I tried that but when I put some test data in I get back the original unaltered list.  

How do I access the output?

My test script:

    original_list=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38]]

starting_index=[3,6]

def index_filter(original_list, starting_index):
    return [value[i:] for i, value in zip(starting_index, original_list)]

index_filter(original_list, starting_index)

print(index_filter)

print(original_list)

Comment: The function returns the new list, you assign it to a variable.

Comment: `new_list = index_filter(original_list, starting_index)`

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be obvious from the `return` statement in the function.

Comment: I printed the function name and that gave me <function index_filter at 0x039CC468>

How can I check the output?  Thanks

Comment: Why would you expect printing a function name would print the output?

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar.  That works.  I am very grateful to you.  I spent so long on this, but I didn't have the tools to get there myself.

Comment: I copied your suggestion for a similar use I had later in my program.  I needed to extract the last value from numerous lists, and used a variant on the code you supplied.  Thanks again.  I was a bit surprised when it worked! You taught me something.